# Open GL can't draw some triangles

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry

I drawed a triangle `{(0,0), (1,0), (0,1)}`. Now i want to draw a second one. But for some reason not any triangle draws. For example triangle: `{(1.5654, 1.2), (1.1, 1.4564), (1.5, 1.15)}` is drawn normal, but triangle `{(1,1), (1,0), (0, 1)}` doesn't appear. Hear the code i use to draw:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
   invers_sh.setAttributeValue(b_colorLoc, colors[0]);
   glVertex2d(1.5654, 1.2);

   invers_sh.setAttributeValue(b_colorLoc, colors[1]);
   glVertex2d(1.1, 1.4564);

   invers_sh.setAttributeValue(b_colorLoc, colors[2]);
   glVertex2d(1.5, 1.15);
glEnd();
```

For first triangle it's the same code (but coordinates are different). I tryed to unite both drawings (in one glBegin/glEnd) - same result. What i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to draw all vertices in a clockwise or counter clockwise order depending on frontface setting, you can google it for more details.

Comment: This is only true if backface culling is enabled. It's disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the other answer, you need to draw the vertices for all triangles in the same order, clockwise or counter-clockwise (OpenGL default).
To correct the ordering, just swap out the first and last vertex.

You can control this behaviour (called FaceCulling) with OpenGL-commands like [glCullFace](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glCullFace.xml), [glFrontFace](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml) and glEnable/glDisable with `GL_CULL_FACE`.